# Applying patch automatically to file from a package each time the latter is upgraded

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

There is a [bug](https://github.com/dirruk1/gnome-breeze/issues/73) in `breeze-gtk-theme` package and I have a [patch](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tMNtXGj7QJ/) for it. Currently I apply the patch manually each time this package is upgraded. I also would like to remove `--verbose` option from `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/95dbus_update-activation-env` and I don't like doing it all manually. I also wouldn't like just hooking to **any** upgrade like described in this [article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-hook-a-script-command-to-apt-get-upgrade-command/), I want to execute patching exclusively when the package with specific file is upgraded.

This is **not** about [patches to files that need compilation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/404213/24383) it's just about config/text files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could merely add a test to your post-upgrade hook.

```
function test_for_theme(){
  // Scrape /var/log/apt/history.log for newest upgrades
  // Return 0 if $PACKAGE_NAME is not in the log
  // Return a different integer if $PACKAGE_NAME is in the log
  tail -n4 /var/log/apt/history.log | grep Upgrade | grep -c $PACKAGE_NAME
  }

if [ test_for_theme -ne 0 ]; then
  apply_patch
  do_other_things
  notify_me
fi
exit 0
```